# What is the use of firebase messaging in telegram

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, telegram

I downloaded the android version source code from [here](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram).
Part of the instructions are:

Go to https://console.firebase.google.com/, create two android apps with application IDs org.telegram.messenger and org.telegram.messenger.beta, turn on firebase messaging and download google-services.json, which should be copied to the same folder as TMessagesProj.

Does anyone know what is the use of this?

I have a problem with missing chats and messages and I think I may be related to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those are instructions to create your own version of Telegram.

It is obviously using the [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging). The won't give you access to theire FCM project settings so you need to create your own project and use them for your notifications.

If you have issues with Telegram installed on your device this won't help you.

Comment: I have issues with this version that I compiled myself.
I'm trying to figure it out.
Why do I need my own FCM? How do I get messages from other users if I use my FCM and they are using their FCM?

Comment: You need your own because the owner of the source code don't want to share his with anyone. And you can't get messages in your App from the FCM configurations of other users. Each Project has it's own FCM. If someone else use another one to compile a different App you can't get messages from that different App.